# Mobile Site Redirection is happening after full load of complete page

Tags: javascript, mobile, mobile-browser

I am using JavaScript Function provided by http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ . Now when I open my site in mobile browser it starts opening original non-mobile(Desktop) site. And when the Desktop site is fully loaded then it redirects to mobile site.In short it redirects after pageload.

> My site URL : [www.xeemez.blogspot.com](http://www.xeemez.blogspot.com)

What I wanted was that the mobile site loades automatically without an intermediate desktop site when opened from mobile devices.I don't know what went wrong.But that intermediate site makes it very annoying to open on mobile site.Below is a JavaScript provided.And I have incorporated it at the top of the page's coding.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function(a,b){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.location=b})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,&#39;http://www.xeemez.blogspot.com?m=1&#39;);

    </script>
```

Comment: Which script of http://detectmobilebrowsers.com did you use?

Comment: JavaScript Code provided on that site.

Comment: Where did you include the script? How do you call it?

Comment: I have included the script in head section.

Comment: For clarity, could you add the exact question you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

How about a bit different solution? It detects the screen size and if its under a certain value redirects:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "mobile.html";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I took a look at your current code, I saw this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(function clic(){
var w=window.innerWidth;
var h=window.innerHeight;
if(w<700 && h<700){
 window.location.assign("http://www.xeemez.blogspot.com?m=1");
}
});
```

Now, at cursory glass, I believe the following line is the problem:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

Basically, you're saying "as soon as the document has executed the event 'ready', then run this function"  - so that completely makes sense.

Your site is loading, and THEN the mobile detection code you wrote is running.  If your intent is to execute the redirect before the page loads, you need to make sure your code is not surrounded by an event handler for document ready.

Comment: That was good analyzation but now I don't have those lines of code anymore.and Then also the effect is same.Actually I had added those lines lines just few days ago in vehemence that it will work.But the code wasn't working either.